# How to add the double headed arrow mark in equation

Tags: equations

[image]

[image]

How to include these symbols in equation? I'm unable to find these

Comment: sorry sir i didnt get you, i need equation as the image included i did it in mathtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol you are searching for if \leftrightarrows or \rightleftarrows :

```
$a \overset{k}{\leftrightarrows} b$
```

[image]